# Duplicating value from one form to another

Tags: javascript, forms

Say, I have got a form which uses the same values as my other form but the first form contains data which I would like to have on my second form. Such as something from a drop-down list box. I am still a noob at HTML and dont know how to do this. Any assistance is gratefully appreciated!

Comment: You want to put values from a form to another, in the same page? Or print in on another page?

Comment: Both of my forms are located on the same page.

Comment: You want to send a form in the page, and print the same values in the other form or do it real-time with javascript?

Comment: I just want to transfer/copy the value from one form to another form. They are both on the same page and I dont mind how I/you do it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're making a Billing & Shipping forms, and you want to have a button "copy billing info to shipping info", right?

Comment: Post some code you have already written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript:

```
<form>
   <input type="text" name="textBox" id="textBox" onchange="document.getElementById('textBox2').value = document.getElementById('textBox').value;">
</form>

<form>
   <input type="text" name="textBox2" id="textBox2">
</form>
```

You can do this for any field.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, it does work. I forgot to assign id's to my fields and assumed it was the "name"

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var form1,
i = 1;
while (form1 = document.getElementById("form1_input" + i)) {
    document.getElementById("form2_input" + i).value = form1.value;
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: This constantly updates it right? Because my field can change while the user is on the page and not when just the page starts

Comment: Tested the code, but it does not transfer the value from my combobox to my hidden field ;(